# LibGDX on Netbeans - android.os does not exist

Tags: java, android, netbeans, libgdx

There are many answers as to how to fix this problem on Eclipse, but none for Netbeans. The libgdx desktop project runs great, but my Android project says "package android.os does not exist".

Furthermore, when I try to create a new Android project in Netbeans (NOT in libgdx, just by creating a new Android project), it works perfectly fine.

There seems to be a problem with libgdx/Android-sdk communication, but after searching for answers online, I can't seem to figure it out!

I can post code if needed.

EDIT: I must have changed something, but the error is slightly different now. Instead of "android.os does not exist", it says "cannot find class Bundle in android.os". Here are some things I've tried:

1. Creating a simple Android application by using File-->New project works fine and is emulated correctly.
2. Creating a new libgdx project with just the basic structure still results in an error in my Android project.
3. When I BUILD my original android project, no errors are found.
4. When I RUN my original android project without an AVD running, it says "error: device not found", then BUILD FAILED.
5. When I RUN my original android project WITH an AVD running, it says BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but there is this error:

`Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher} does not exist.`

What's really stumping me is why it says build successful when the project itself says it can't find android.os.Bundle.

It appears now that some classes in android.os are found and usable in Netbeans, but Bundle and many others aren't!

Answer (score 1):

From LIBGDX's wiki https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans:

> Running Your Project
>
> In the project view:
>   • Android: make sure you have a device connected. Right click your Android project,  Tasks -> installDebug .

After doing this my project ran successfully.  (I was experiencing the same error.)

Comment: Netbeans still has no idea what or where android is but this does allow me to install the application without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First possible variant - Libgdx has a [gradle support](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) just set up gradle build script and run it from the console.

Second - import your project into [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/?utm_expid=85132606-37.5-enLWJnTxyshuS9opeVLA.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F) / [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) and compile your project from there.

If you are really want to save your time. Do not try to use NetBeans for Android development, I believe you know that it has no official Android support.

Comment: I've successfully deployed Android apps on Netbeans before. I had to reinstall it because I got a new computer and I may have messed something up. I know it works, I just need help from someone who has used Netbeans + Android